# How to read fields using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and since I'm working with tabular data I was recommended to use pandas to process and structure the data that I'll be working with.

I'm reading this file:

```
Accel(m/s^2) 0.2518 0.0072 9.8201  
Accel(m/s^2) 0.2369 0.0036 9.8201  
Accel(m/s^2) 0.2477 0.0048 9.8369
```

Using the following code:

```
file_name = '/Users/MT/Desktop/Accel_Data.txt';

accel_data = { 'X': [], 'Y': [], 'Z': []  }   

data = pd.read_csv(file_name,sep = '\t');

   for line in data:
accel_data['X'].append(line[1])
accel_data['Y'].append(line[2])
accel_data['Z'].append(line[3])
```

I expected the `accel_data` dictionary to look like the following:

```
{ 'X': [0.2518,0.2369,0.2477], 'Y': [0.0072, 0.0036, 0.0048], 'Z': [9.8201, 9.8201, 9.8369]  }
```

But it looked like this instead:

```
{ 'X': ['c', ':', ':', ':'], 'Y': [ 'c',  ' ',  ' ', ' '], 'Z': [ 'e',  '0',  '0', '9']  }
```

This work could be done in excel or matlab, which I'm more accustomed to using, but I need to learn how to use python to transition into a more versatile coding language for processing this type of data. Any help would be thoroughly appreciated!

Comment: can you try running `data.head()` to see what the dataframe looks like? Or `print(data)`

Comment: `sep = '\t'` may be the issue. Is your file tab delimited?

Comment: @Smurphy0000 the output looks like this [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NrmDQ9bxxmctU9UUqcx4jZt5TMhFPpBe/view?usp=sharing). 

Also, pandas read_csv function defaults to a delimiter = none. So I don't believe that the file tab is delimited

Comment: You might need to use `data.iterrows()` - see here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue seems to be the use of `sep = '\t'` and your file seems to be space delimited.
change your line that reads to this

```py
data = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep = ' ') # note tha space
```

and if your file doesn't have a header then do

```py
data = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep = ' ', header=None)
```

Now let's go a bit extra.
There doesn't seem to be a reason to do what you are doing for putting the data into that dictionary, you can assign the header for the dataframe like this

```py
columns = ['formula', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
data = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep = ' ', header=None, names=columns)
```

which would give you

```
        formula       X       Y       Z
0  Accel(m/s^2)  0.2518  0.0072  9.8201


1  Accel(m/s^2)  0.2369  0.0036  9.8201


2  Accel(m/s^2)  0.2477  0.0048  9.8369
```

The power of pandas comes with using it as a dataframe, if you are to extract the data and convert it into a dictionary then you lost that.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! I couldn't upvote the answer because I'm new but that did exactly what I needed and I'll be sure to store it in a dataframe going forward to take advantage of pandas. Thanks again!

Comment: @MTurra well, if this answer does answer your question then you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark under the vote buttons, you are welcome :D